# Even and odd proof - if n is even then $n^{2} -1$ is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that if $n$ is even then $n^2 -1$ is odd?

Comment: If $n$ is even, then is $n^2$ odd or even?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** $$n^2-1 = (n-1)(n+1)$$ What can be said of $n-1$ and $n+1$?

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $n$ is even and that $n^2-1$ is even. Then $n^2=(n^2-1)+1$ is odd. Hence $n$ is odd, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

for any $x$, $x$ + $x$ will be even

Now $n$<sup>2</sup> is $n$ + $n$ + ... ($n$ times) and as $n$ is even then $n$ = $m$ + $m$, where $m$ = $n / 2$ is also an integer,

now $n$<sup>2</sup> = $m$ + $m$ + ... ($2n$ times)
Or $n$<sup>2</sup> = $p$ + $p$ , where $p$ = $m$ + $m$ + ....($n$ times)

Therefore $n$<sup>2</sup> is even and hence $n$<sup>2</sup> - 1 is odd.

Comment: You should take advantage of LaTeX by wrapping math in $\$$ symbols, instead of making math bold. For example, $x$ instead of **x**

Comment: @graydad done, didn't knew about it.

Comment: No sweat :) I wasn't trying to be critical. You can do a ton with LaTeX on stackexchange in terms of expressing math.